# Azure resource monitoring issue

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Questions that I have is:

1. How SQL Virtual machine is getting created in my azure subscription as I am not creating it through the Azure portal or neither through an ARM template?
2. I am installing SQL server express edition in my VM through Microsoft's site does this triggers a SQL VM resource creation in Azure as well?
3. How to figure out the resource creation/deployments in Azure, where to find these logs?
4. How to recreate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the resource group the vm is in click Deployments:

[image]

This will give the list of deployments and hopefully give you an idea where the deployment came from.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but this is not working as I cannot see the Sql vm deployment, I can only see the VM deployment which is fine and there isn't any sql vm resource in its template, the problem I have not created any diagnostics, so I don't have any update on actual sql vm deployment time. I just want to know what are the possible ways you can create sql vm resource in azure, also how to re-create this issue? I have no idea about it or how sql vm is getting deployed on the azure subscription.